# Kotlin constructor binding is not applicable to target 'class'

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

i am new to Kotlin. I am trying to achieve same thing, i would do in java.

in application.yaml, i have this config:

```
conference:
 plans:
   - plan-id: P1_1
     product-id: product1
     employee-limit: 50
   - plan-id: P1_2
     product-id: product2
     employee-limit: 100
```

then i want to create data class, so that , when i run the springboot application, this class is automatically loaded and validated

in Conferences.kt file:

```
package com.company.conferenceplanservice.config.properties

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.ConstructorBinding
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated

@Validated
@ConstructorBinding
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "conference")
data class Plans(
    @field:NotEmpty val plans: Set<Plan>
)

@Validated
@ConstructorBinding
data class Plan(
    @field:NotBlank val planId: String,
    @field:NotBlank val productId: String,
    val eomployeeLimit: Int
)
```

but always it throws this exception, on both places where ConstructorBinding is written

Kotlin: This annotation is not applicable to target 'class'

springboot 3.0.0, java 18, kotlin 1.7.21

Answer (score 7):

I hope this helps
I no longer use @ConstructingBinding nowadays 
This is How I would have implemented

application.yaml

```
conference:
 plan-id: P1_1
 product-id: product1
```

Conferences.kt

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "conference")
data class Conferences(
    val planId: String,
    val productId: String,
)
```

Usage.kt

```
object MySample {
   fun haveFun(conference : Conference) : String {
      return conference.planId
   } 
}

@Component
class BootLoader(val conference: Conference) : CommandLineRunner {
    override fun run(vararg args: String?) {
        println(MySample.haveFun(conference))
    }
}
```

FYI

"@ConstructingBinding No Longer Needed at the Type Level"
"Improved @ConstructorBinding Detection When using constructor bound @ConfigurationProperties the @ConstructorBinding annotation is no longer required if the class has a single parameterized constructor. If you have more than one constructor, you’ll still need to use @ConstructorBinding to tell Spring Boot which one to use."
"For most users, this updated logic will allow for simpler @ConfigurationProperties classes. If, however, you have a @ConfigurationProperties and you want to inject beans into the constructor rather than binding it, you’ll now need to add an @Autowired annotation."

reference 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConstructorBinding.html

Answer (score 0):

```
@Validated
@ConstructorBinding
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "conference")
data class Plans(
    @field:NotEmpty val plans: Set<Plan>
)

@Validated
@ConstructorBinding
data class Plan(
    @field:NotBlank val planId: String,
    @field:NotBlank val productId: String,
    val eomployeeLimit: Int
)
```

and @ConfigurationPropertiesScan
annotation is needed in main class